# After logging in successfully, the user cannot be read from the symfony session

Tags: php, symfony, session-cookies, php-8.1

I have created a new project where the authentication is supposed to work in sessions. After a successful login, a cookie is created in the login controller, I can use `$this->getUser()`, but when I want to use the same in another controller, the `getUser()` method returns null and in the `PHPSESSID` cookie is set to `deleted`. I tried to create another project but the problem persists.

my security.yaml:

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        App\User\Data\Model\UserData:
            algorithm: argon2i

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\User\Data\Model\UserData
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
            logout:
                path: /logout

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: argon2i
                cost: 4
                time_cost: 3
                memory_cost: 10
```

my framework.yaml:

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    http_method_override: false

    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native

    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

edit:

User Entity:

```
    <?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\User\Data\Model;

use App\Core\Util\Trait\Timestamp;
use App\User\Permission\Model\UserPermission;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserData implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    use Timestamp;

    private ?int $id = null;

    private string $name;

    private string $surname;

    private string $email;

    private ?string $password;

    private Collection $permissions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->permissions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(): self
    {
        $this->password = null;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return ["ROLE_USER"];
//        return array_map(
//            fn($permission) => $permission->getName(),
//            $this->permissions->toArray()
//        );
    }

    public function setRoles(UserPermission ...$permissions): self
    {
        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            if (!$this->permissions->contains($permission)) {
                $this->permissions[] = $permission;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Entity Mapping:

```
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="App\User\Data\Model\UserData">
        <id name="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

        <field name="name" type="string" length="50"/>
        <field name="surname" type="string" length="50"/>
        <field name="email" type="string" length="100"/>
        <field name="password" type="string" length="96"/>

        <many-to-many field="permissions" target-entity="App\User\Permission\Model\UserPermission">
            <join-table name="user_permission">
                <join-columns>
                    <join-column name="user_id"/>
                </join-columns>
                <inverse-join-columns>
                    <join-column name="permission_id"/>
                </inverse-join-columns>
            </join-table>
        </many-to-many>

        <field name="updatedAt" type="datetime_immutable" nullable="true"/>
        <field name="createdAt" type="datetime_immutable"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Can I see please your User entity ?

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz I included entities and mapping in the content of the question